# How to properly invoke the superclass method first when overriding it?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
@Override
public JComponent createControlPanel() {
    super.createControlPanel();
    panel.add(new JLabel("Brain:"));
    brainMode = new JCheckBox("Brain active");
    panel.add(brainMode); 
}

public JComponent createControlPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
}
```

Here I am trying to override the createControlPanel() method in the superclass. The superclass has a 'panel' variable which has already been declared but it seems it cannot be seen here. What should I do so I can use variables declared in the superclass?

Comment: Are you saying that the super class declares the method as `public JComponent createControlPanel(JPanel panel)`? If so, then your method must have the same parameter, otherwise it's not an *override*, and you would simply pass on that parameter in the `super` call.

Comment: No, the superclass method is `public JComponent createControlPanel()`. panel is a variable declared in the superclass that I would like to use in my subclass. Bascially it is a panel that I want to add additional buttons to.

Comment: Since we don't know the super class, it's difficult to help you. Is `panel` a *field variable* or a *local variable* or some other kind of variable? If a field, is it `public`, `private`, `protected`, or package-private? If `private`, it there a `getPanel()` method? What is the `JComponent` return value? From the method name, I would have guessed it to be the panel, in which case you just assign the return value to a local variable, use it, then return it at the end, a part you're missing (returning a `JComponent` object).

Comment: I have added partially(since it is very long) what the superclass looks like

Comment: Sorry, I edited the comment, adding more questions. In particular: What is the return value? Both stub methods are missing the `return` statement. If the super class has `return panel;`, then you already have it, you just forgot to capture the return value from the `super` call.

Comment: Thanks you Andreas. I think I get you. The superclass returns panel.

Comment: You may want to look into the Builder design pattern as one alternative to doing this if you can modify the parent class.  Then you can do things like `ControlPanel panel = ControlPanel.builder().layout(someLayout).labels(someLabels).build();` assuming I understand the intent of your code correctly.